# Copy Horseshoe object and move/shrink it in circle TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf, translate

i want to implement this graphic with TiKz:
[image]

I tried to make the object inside the circle with the plot statement. Is there any better way to do it? And how can I create an object,  move it and shrink it?
Here my Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}




\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\draw [name path=circ] (-5,0) circle (2cm);

\filldraw [gray][name path=huf] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(-3,2)(-1.5,3) (0,0.5) (1.5,3) (3,2) (0,-1.5)};



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

See, if you liked:

[image]

In shifting and scaling of the most left picture probably you will need to find right values by trying ... The code is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=210]
\draw[very thick,fill=gray] (1,0) 
    arc[x radius=12mm, y radius=24mm, start angle=-30, end angle=210]
    -- ++ (-0.5,0)
    arc[x radius=18mm, y radius=32mm, start angle=210, end angle=-30]
    -- cycle;
\draw[red] (0,4.25) circle (5);
\fill[red] (0,4.25) circle (2mm);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=110mm,rotate=210]
\draw[very thick,fill=gray] (1,2)
    arc[x radius=12mm, y radius=24mm, start angle=-30, end angle=210]
    -- ++ (-0.5,0)
    arc[x radius=18mm, y radius=32mm, start angle=210, end angle=-30]
    -- cycle;
\draw[red] (0,4.25) circle (5);
\fill[red] (0,4.25) circle (2mm);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(205mm,-20mm)},rotate=210,scale=0.5]
\draw[very thick,fill=gray] (1,0)
    arc[x radius=12mm, y radius=24mm, start angle=-30, end angle=210]
    -- ++ (-0.5,0)
    arc[x radius=18mm, y radius=32mm, start angle=210, end angle=-30]
    -- cycle;
\draw[red] (0,4.25) circle (5);
\fill[red] (0,4.25) circle (2mm);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```